# Customize jsonb key sort order

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in PostgreSQL with some data:

```
create table t2 (
    key jsonb,
    value jsonb
);

insert into t2(key, value) values ('1', '"test 1"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('2', '"test 2"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('3', '"test 3"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[]', '"test 4"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1]', '"test 5"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[2]', '"test 6"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[3]', '"test 7"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1, 2]', '"test 8"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1, 2, 3]', '"test 9"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1, 3]', '"test 10"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1,2,4]', '"test 11"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1, 2,4]', '"test 12"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1,3,13]', '"test 13"');
insert into t2(key, value) values ('[1, 2, 15]', '"test 15"');
```

And I try to sort these rows like that:

```
SELECT key FROM t2 order by key;
```

The result is:

```
[]
1
2
3
[1]
[2] <==
[3] <==
[1, 2]
[1, 3] <==
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 15]
[1, 3, 13]
```

But what I need is

```
[]
1
2
3
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 15]
[1, 3] <==
[1, 3, 13]
[2] <==
[3] <==
```

is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this will be like

```
SELECT * FROM t2
ORDER BY case when key= '[]'  then 1
when key= '1'  then 2
when key= '2'  then 3
when key= '3'  then 4
when key= '[1]'  then 5
when key= '[1, 2]'  then 6
when key= '[1, 2, 3]'  then 7
when key='[1, 2, 15]' then 8
when key='[1, 3]' then 9
when key='[1, 3, 13]' then 10
when key='[2]' then 11
when key= '[3]'  then 12    
end asc
```

same way you can defined your own custom sorting logic in your query.

Answer (score 0):

mixing types will be some pain and you probably did not mean there goint to be only three values :) but still an idea:

```
SELECT key FROM t2 order by (key->>0)::text::int,(key->>1)::int ,(key->>2)::int;
```

will give:

`"[1, 2, 3]"
"[1, 2, 4]"
"[1, 2, 4]"
"[1, 2, 15]"
"[1, 2]"
"[1, 3, 13]"
"[1, 3]"
"1"
"[1]"
"2"
"[2]"
"3"
"[3]"
"[]"`